# Just curious about SQL Joins

Tags: sql-server, ansi-sql

I'm just curious here. If I have two tables, let's say Clients and Orders.
Clients have a unique and primary key ID_Client. Orders have an ID_Client field also and a relation to maintain integrity to Client's table by ID_Client field.

So when I want to join both tables i do:

```
SELECT 
    Orders.*, Clients.Name 
FROM 
    Orders 
INNER JOIN 
    Clients ON Clients.ID_Client = Orders.ID_Client
```

So if I took the job to create the primary key, and the relation between the tables,

Is there a reason why I need to explicitly include the joined columns in on clause?

Why can't I do something like:

```
SELECT 
    Orders.*, Clients.Name 
FROM 
    Orders 
INNER JOIN 
    Clients
```

So SQL should know which columns relate both tables...

Comment: Why can't I just write 'Get me the records I want'?

Comment: Yes because if sql always just assumed it was the foreign key columns to use as the join predicates it wouldn't allow for the flexibility if you did for some reason want to join on other column(s). Defining relations is NOT about making your life easier as a developer, it is about maintaining the integrity of the data.

Comment: @Tom: It would be nice when you write that sql in the first time. it would be **HELL** when someone else have to read it 18 months later, and the sql contains 10 tables, and he has to check the relationships of all of them to find out what wrong with the sql.

Comment: @Tom no it wouldn't, it would create a lot of WTF situations. A foreign key *constraint* is a **constraint**, not a relation. Its existence doesn't mean that two tables can be joined automatigally. Never mind views, CTEs, the results of functions or TVPs which don't have any such constraints

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had this same question once and I found a great explanation for it on [Database Administrator Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/15152/), the answer below was the one that I found to be the best, but you can refer to the link for additional explanations as well.

> A foreign key is meant to **constrain** the data. ie enforce
>   referential integrity. That's it. Nothing else.
>
> 1. You can have multiple foreign keys to the same table. Consider the following where a shipment has a starting point, and an ending point.
>
>    ```
>    table: USA_States
>    StateID
>    StateName
>
>    table: Shipment
>    ShipmentID
>    PickupStateID Foreign key
>    DeliveryStateID Foreign key
>    ```
>
>    You may want to join based on the pickup state. Maybe you want to join on the delivery state. Maybe you want to perform 2 joins for
>      both! The sql engine has no way of knowing what you want.
> 2. You'll often cross join scalar values. Although scalars are usually the result of intermediate calculations, sometimes you'll have a
>      special purpose table with exactly 1 record. If the engine tried to
>      detect a foriegn key for the join.... it wouldn't make sense because
>      cross joins never match up a column.
> 3. In some special cases you'll join on columns where neither is unique. Therefore the presence of a PK/FK on those columns is
>      impossible.
> 4. You may think points 2 and 3 above are not relevant since your questions is about when there **IS** a single PK/FK relationship
>      between tables. However the presence of single PK/FK between the
>      tables does not mean you can't have other fields to join on in
>      addition to the PK/FK.  The sql engine would not know which fields you
>      want to join on.
> 5. Lets say you have a table "USA_States", and 5 other tables with a FK to the states.  The "five" tables also have a few foreign keys to
>      each other. Should the sql engine automatically join the "five" tables
>      with "USA_States"?  Or should it join the "five" to each other? Both?
>      You could set up the relationships so that the sql engine enters an
>      infinite loop trying to join stuff together. In this situation it's
>      impossible fore the sql engine to guess what you want.
>
> **In summary:** PK/FK has nothing to do with table joins. They are separate unrelated things. It's just an accident of nature that you
>   often join on the PK/FK columns.
>
> Would you want the sql engine to guess if it's a full, left, right, or
>   inner join? I don't think so. Although that would arguably be a lesser
>   sin than guessing the columns to join on.

Comment: You can also add 6: What if after you write the stored procedure or view, someone add a new foreign key?

Comment: The idea could be "If there's no On clause AND tables have only one foreing key relation, try to join by them. If not SQL Would ask to explicit specify ON clause". It's the same when you join two tables (a and b) with a common field name and use SELECT a.*, b.*. If A and B have same field names, SQL gives an error. Same principle here

Comment: Your link is horribly broken. Also, if you cite, please use a quote section.

Comment: @Tomalak - Thanks for the advice, I have updated the link and the quote section.

Comment: FYI I've formatted the code sample into the quote as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't explicitly give the field names in the query, SQL doesn't know which fields to use. You won't always have fields that are named the same and you won't always be joining on the primary key. For example, a relationship could be between two foreign key fields named "Client_Address" and "Delivery_Address". In that case, you can easily see how you would need to give the field name.

As an example:

```
SELECT o.*, c.Name 
FROM Clients c
INNER JOIN Orders o 
ON o.Delivery_Address = c.Client_Address
```

Comment: Ok. As long as i can see fields names doesnt matter, because i create a relation between both tables regardless of fields names. SQL Could suppose that if i didnt's specify on clause, then it tryes to join by relation between tables.

Comment: No. There is no relation defined. It's a foreign key *constraint*, not a relation. If you insist on theory, the *table* is the relation between the data stored in its fields.

Comment: You could also create a View in SQL Server to handle the relationship. Views act similar to tables and they are built off of a query.

Comment: And views or CTEs have no constraints, so changing the syntax of JOIN just to cover a few edge cases wouldn't really help.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a reason why do i need to explicit include then joinned fields in on clause?

Yes, because you still need to tell the database server what you want. "Do what I mean" is not within the capabilities of any software system so far.

Foreign keys are tools for enforcing data integrity. They do not dictate how you can join tables. You can join *on any condition that is expressible through an SQL expression*.

In other words, a join clause relates two tables to each other by a freely definable condition that needs to evaluate to true given the two rows from left hand side and the right hand side of the join. It does not have to be the foreign key, it can be any condition.

Want to find people that have last names equal to products you sell?

```
SELECT 
  Products.Name, 
  Clients.LastName
FROM 
  Products 
  INNER JOIN Clients ON Products.Name = Clients.LastName
```

There isn't even a foreign key between Products and Clients, still the whole thing works.

Comment: I agree but that's not my point. I know i could join by any fields. All i'm saying is that SQL could be smart to know that if i don't specify on clause, could try to use foreing key. I'm sure you agree with me that could drasticaly reduce sql sintaxis on multiple joins.

Comment: @ericpap no, not at all. It would make things a lot more confusing, especially in multi-table joins. You would have to look up the schema of all tables involved to find out why a certain row was returned or not.

Comment: @ericpap *"All I'm saying is that the computer could be smart and simply do what I find most appropriate at the time."* ;-)

Comment: You're absolute wrigth on your second coment. Didn't think about that. thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's like that. :)

The sql standard says that you have to say on which columns to join. The constraints are just for referential integrity. With mysql the join support "join table using (column1, column2)" but then those columns have to be present in both tables

Comment: I hope nobody uses the non-standard `JOIN TABLE USING()` form just to save a few characters

Answer (score 0):

Reasons why this behaviour is not default

Because one Table can have multiple columns referencing back to one column in another table.

In a lot of legacy databases there are no Foreign key constraints but yet the columns are “Supposed to be” referencing some column in some other table.

The join conditions are not always as simple as A.Column = B.Column .  and the list goes on…….

Microsoft developers were intelligent enough to let us make this decision rather than them guessing that it will always be A.Column = B.Column

Comment: This has nothing to do with Microsoft, it's the SQL standard. Besides, think about views, CTEs and all other non-table constructs

Comment: I agree but that's not my point. I know i could join by any fields. All i'm saying is that SQL could be smart to know that if i don't specify on clause, could try to use foreing key. I'm sure you agree with me that could drasticaly reduce sql sintaxis on multiple joins